# Code working in Localhost but it dosent work in online website in java using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets, struts2

I had made one web application in Java using frameworks -struts 2.0, hibernate 3.0, and tiles 2.0 . 
and in my local system i am using JDK 1.6, apache- tomcat 6.0 and my SQL 5.5
when i registering the user it works OK in my local system on my local-host.
But when i registering on http://www.shreerajinvestment.com/Home/registration.jsp its not working properly.

what i have to do...?

**In Online redirected on error action. But in local-host redirected on success action recored added successfully and registered.**

**struts code**

```
<action name="registration" class="Registration" >

    <result name="input" >/registration.jsp</result>
    <result name="error" >/error.jsp</result>
    <result name="success" type="tiles" >home</result>
</action>
```

This is **hibernateConfiguration.xml** file

```
 <hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name="connection.useUnicode" >true</property>
    <property name="connection.characterEncoding" >UTF-8</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class" >com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url" >jdbc:mysql://mysiteIP:3306/databasename</property> 
    <property name="connection.username" >root</property>
    <property name="connection.password" >admin</property>
    <property name="dialect" >org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class" >thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" >org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

    <mapping resource="pojo/registrationpojo.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="pojo/lifepojo.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="pojo/gipojo.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="pojo/mfpojo.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="pojo/cdpojo.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="pojo/fdpojo.hbm.xml" />

</session-factory>
```

This is **registration.java** file

```
package SRI.User;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import pojo.RegistrationPojo;
import admin.Common;
import admin.HibernateUtils;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Registration extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private HttpServletRequest myrequest = null;
public List<Registration> regpojo = null;

public HttpServletRequest getMyrequest() {
    return myrequest;
}
public void setMyrequest(HttpServletRequest myrequest) {
    this.myrequest = myrequest;
}
public List<Registration> getRegpojo() {
    return regpojo;
}
public void setRegpojo(List<Registration> regpojo) {
    this.regpojo = regpojo;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}
public void setFirst_name(String firstName) {
    first_name = firstName;
}
public Date getDob() {
    return dob;
}
public void setDob(Date dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}
    //other fields getter - seter

private String first_name = null;
private Date dob = null;
    //other fields

private int flag;
private String re = null;
private Common mCommon = new Common(); 

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public String execute() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        Session session = HibernateUtils.getSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        regpojo = session.createQuery("select m.uname from RegistrationPojo m").list();

        if(regpojo.size() == 0)
        {
            //code to add record in the table
            RegistrationPojo p1=new RegistrationPojo();
            p1.setFirst_name(getFirst_name());
            p1.setDob(mCommon.ChangeDateformat(getDob()));
            //set other fields 
            session.save(p1);
            tx.commit();

            System.out.println("Registration Successfully");
            re=SUCCESS;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0; i<regpojo.size(); i++)
            {
                if(username.equals(regpojo.get(i)))
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = 0;
                }
            }
            if(flag == 0)
            {

                    //code to add record in the table
                    RegistrationPojo p1=new RegistrationPojo();
                    p1.setFirst_name(getFirst_name());
                    p1.setDob(mCommon.ChangeDateformat(getDob()));
                    //set other fields 
                    session.save(p1);
                    tx.commit();                

                                    System.out.println("Registration Successfully");
                re=SUCCESS;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
                addFieldError("un", "User Name is not Available");
                re=INPUT;   
            }
        }
        HttpSession s=myrequest.getSession(true);
        s.setAttribute("uname",username);
        s.setAttribute("pwd",password);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        re = ERROR;
        System.out.println("Connection Failed: "+ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return re;
}

public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) 
{
    this.myrequest=request;
}
}
```

This is **error log on web server** file

```
Connection Failed: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
at SRI.User.Registration.execute(Registration.java:155)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:399)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:262)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:213)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.intercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:161)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:206)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:115)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:143)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.intercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:115)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:170)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:507)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:421)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'shreeraj_root'@'209.59.190.236' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:798)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3700)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1203)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2572)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1485)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:417)
... 119 more
```

Comment: <property name="connection.url" >jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename</property> << this ???

Comment: yes i know that but how to get my website's database URL...? I haven't any idea about how to get that connection URL from web.....

Comment: your Ip :) check this www.whatismyip.com

Comment: OK thanks can u give me detail code for that        what i have to write instead of **jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename**

Comment: replace ur localhost with ur ip :)

Comment: i had replace the localhost to my website ip... but still its not redirecting on success page.... what i have to do....? i had added error log....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you specified proper database address in connection url? The file which you have posted shows localhost. Check it once.

Comment: yes i know that but how to get my website's database URL...? I haven't any idea about how to get that connection URL from web.....

Comment: You must be knowing where your database is hosted , right? You will have to put that machine's ip address in the connection url

Comment: k i had replace the localhost to my website ip... but still its not redirecting on success page.   i had getting errorlog on web server which i had mention above